# Keep form opened if cancel button clicked VB2012

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to know what code I can type in the second part of the first if statement below, to keep the form active when cancel button is clicked.

```
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Message prompt to ask if the user really want to exit
    MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "MDCS")

    If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Find_Client).Any Or Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Form_items).Any Then
            MsgBox("Close all opened windows before the main", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "MDCS")
        Else
            ' Call sub that close the program
            Me.Close()
            Dim items As New Form_items, clients As New Find_Client
            items.Close()
            clients.Close()
            'Stop Stopwatch
            Timer1.Stop()
            Me.StopWatch.Stop()

            'Mark Stopwatch value
            intTimerValues = Val(Timer_Label.Text)
        End If
    Else
        ???
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: exit_program. I call it in the exit button to close the application. There should be a possibility to leave the program actif when a cancel button is clicked.

Comment: You haven't shown us any code that actually exits the program.

Comment: Put the code in the `Closing` event of your form and if your form shouldn't be closed, cancel it through the ClosingEventArgs: `e.Cancel = True`.

Comment: Please check the code again. the e.cancel is not accepted in the editor.

Comment: He said the code should go in the **`Form_Closing`** event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is incorrect.

You show a message box

```
'Message prompt to ask if the user really want to exit
MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "MDCS")
```

but you do not test its return value.

What you *actually* do is test the value of a *constant*, `MsgBoxResult.Ok`

```
If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
```

[`MsgBoxResult.Ok` is a member of an enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c42kya8.aspx) that evaluates to 1. So basically, what you have is

```
If 1 Then
```

Well, that *always* evaluates to `True`, so the `If` block is always run. You never get to the `Else` block.

Fix the code by actually testing the result of the `MsgBox` call:

```
Dim MsgBoxResult As result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", _
                                    MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, _
                                    "MDCS")
If result = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
    ' ...
    'Close the form.
    Me.Close()
Else
    ' ...
    ' Don't write code to close the form and it won't be closed.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the current active form should be displayed **automatically** although you do not put any code in the Else function if you put your code in a specific button event handler .
Well after reading your reply in the comments above, I assume that you are putting your code in **Form_Closing** event , if it is the case, then you should put ***e.Cancel()*** in the Else part of your code .

Comment: When I leave the else part empty, the program shuts down the time the cancel button is clicked.

Comment: Please check the code again. the e.cancel is not accepted in the editor.

Comment: I found the answer. I just needed to to start the if statement with MsgBoxResult.cancel